# in spark, how do get a denseMatrix from RowMatrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark

UPDATED:

I have the following representation :

```
scala> val B = sc.parallelize(Seq(Vectors.dense(5.0, 1.0, -2.0), Vectors.dense(10.0, 2.0, -9.0), Vectors.dense(12.0, 8.0, 2.0)))

B: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = ParallelCollectionRDD[222] at parallelize at <console>:48
```

I represented it as a RowMatrix by doing the following:

```
scala> val rowB = new RowMatrix(B)
rowB: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@4c1838e
```

I would like to know how to represent this as a denseMatrix in Breeze
Is that possible?

Im a novice coder in spark so I am looking for materials that can lead me understanding if the function is possible since I would like to do a MATRIX MULTIPLICATION of a ROWMATRIX and a DenseMatrix?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit !

Comment: @Shivansh.. I am trying to learn how to represent certain Matrix in spark.. please see edit on the question for further details